# Cannot resolve method addNotification ()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I replaced this (it allows me to show the notification only when the app was open):

```
private void addNotification() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                NotificationChannel channel =
                        new NotificationChannel("MyNotifications", "MyNotifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyNotifications")
                    .setContentTitle("Chiamata in arrivo da "+ receiverUserName)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText("Apri FtoF per partecipare alla videochiamata");
            NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            manager.notify(999, builder.build());
        }
```

with this (it allowed me to show the notification even when the app was closed:

```
public class PushNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //at this point the context has the permission to create remote views
        addNotification(context);
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

    private void addNotification(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel channel =
                    new NotificationChannel("MyNotifications", "MyNotifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "MyNotifications")
                .setContentTitle("Chiamata in arrivo")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText("Apri FtoF per partecipare alla videochiamata");
        NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        manager.notify(999, builder.build());
    }

}
```

But now on line 283 this error appears: Cannot resolve method 'addNotification ()'
Does anyone know why?
Complete Code: https://codeshare.io/5D8EgE
lines (111-136) (283)
Thank you